# How to make sub forms?

Tags: php, forms

I have a main form that has questions inside it that populate.  Each question needs to be able to upload a file.

This is where I have issues, because you can't have a form within a form.  With file uploads they like to be their own form.  The outer form (`answer_audit.php?action=post`) tries to dominate the sub form.  Is there a solution to this?

I broke down the code to show what I mean, I can add more code if you need it, but I am trying to limit this to PHP and html only as much as possible:

```
<form role="form" action="./answer_audit.php?action=post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="auditForm" id="auditForm"  >

  <a title='Upload file' href='#' do_disable='$disabled' id=$row[questionID] class='btn btn-default btn-xs “  data-toggle='modal'  data-target='#uploaded_files_$row[questionID]’>

  <!-- modal pop up -->
  <div class='modal fade' style='z-index:10000' id='uploaded_files_$row[questionID]' role='dialog'>
  <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
     <div class='modal-content'>
       <div class='modal-header'>
       <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'></button>
        <h4 class='modal-title'>Title</h4>   
       </div>                                           
      <div class='modal-body'>                              
      <form id='my_form_1$row[questionID]' name='form' action='ajax/upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='_blank'>
         <h1>Upload File</h1>   
         <strong>File: </strong><input name='myFile' id='myFile' type='file' />
         <input id='$row[questionID]' class='upload_button' name='action' value='Upload'  type='button' />               
         <iframe id='my_iframe' name='my_iframe' src=''></iframe>  
      </form>                           
      </div>
   <div class='modal-footer'>                                       
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>              
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success finish_button" type="button" ID="" value="Finish"/>

 </form>
```

Comment: HTML doesn't allow subforms

Comment: [Forms simply cannot be nested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms). Have a look there for examples on how to get around this restriction.